# what is the mod in math formula stand for and using it python

Tags: python, math, geocoding, trigonometry, equation

I want to use this formula to calculate the angle between two geocode points in python:

The formula:

```
 tc1 = mod(atan2(sin(lon1 - lon2) * cos(lat2),
       cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon1-lon2)),
       2 * pi)
```

My code:

```
 tc1 = (atan2(sin(self.gdt1[1] - self.target_area[1]) * cos(self.target_area[1]),
                     cos(self.gdt1[0]) * sin(self.gdt1[0]) - sin(self.target_area[0]) * cos(
                         self.gdt1[1] - self.target_area[1])), 2 * pi)
```

what does the mod stand for and how to represent it in python (It can't be modulo, right?)
and how can I test to see if the output is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod` is the [mathematical modulo function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (the remainder after dividing the first argument by the second) - in Python this is represented by the `%` operator. The following function is equivalent:

```
tc1 = atan2(sin(self.gdt1[1] - self.target_area[1]) * cos(self.target_area[1]), cos(self.gdt1[0]) * sin(self.gdt1[0]) - sin(self.target_area[0]) *cos(self.gdt1[1] - self.target_area[1])) % 2*pi
```

In your function, this makes sense, as any angle over `2*pi` radians (a full circle) is equivalent to the angle when you subtract `2*pi` radians.

For example, `3*pi` radians is equivalent in angle *direction* to `1*pi` radians. (540 degrees is equal in direction to 180 degrees)